# Spacing characters during Pull Request code review

Tags: github, whitespace

So I am using github pull requests for my code review needs and my only issue is that I cannot tell whether a person is using tabs or spaces for indentation. We have a standard here on this and you can fail code review for using the wrong one. Is there a way to tell which they are using with github or will I have to manually open up the file in my editor to tell the difference?

Comment: Use Travis and check for correct whitespace there. This can be checked automatically rather than manually, so why bother doing it by hand.

Comment: We've usually used language-specific linters for this kind of styleguide adherence (jslint, rubocop, etc.), and those can be run in a CI tool like Travis

Comment: Due to circumstances out of my control at my company this is simply not an option for at least the next 3 or 4 months. This is why I am asking if you can do this with github. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell which they are using with github or will I have to manually open up the file in my editor to tell the difference?

Ideally – neither!

Whenever things can be checked in an automated way, let the computer do the work for you. Checking proper usage of whitespace among many other static rules can be checked with a variety of tools, often called linters. This highly depends on what language your project uses. Of course you can also write your own scrips if you so choose.

What you can do on Github is connect your repository to a CI tool such as Travis. This lets you automatically build all pull requests and check things such as whitespace rules. It also lets you run test suites, code formatting, … – anything you can automate, you can (and should!) run from there to minimize manual work.

Comment: I agree with this answer completely. In about another year this will definitely be the case. However, due to circumstances out of my control at my company this is simply not an option for at least the next 3 or 4 months. This is why I am asking if you can do this with github. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If Travis is not an option right now, you can always write your own Github integration to run some script that checks these things. But as far as actually changing the editor on Github itself goes… AFAIK, that's not possible. See [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) for the necessary APIs.

Comment: If it absolutely must be on the Github page itself and the manual check is fine, it could be possible to write a simple browser script/plugin or Javascript plugin that highlights wrong whitespace.

Comment: Im going to mark this as an answer ...but please insert your last comment as part of the answer. Thanks!